# Division in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TotalMem=$(top -n 1 | grep Mem | awk 'NR==1{print $4}') #integer
UsadoMem=$(top -n 1 | grep Mem | awk 'NR==1{print $8}') #integer
PorcUsado='scale=2;UsadoMem/TotalMem'|bc -l 
echo $PorcUsado
```

The variable `PorcUsado` returns empty. I search for the use of `bc`, but something is wrong...

Comment: fwiw, `read j j j TotalMem j j j UsadoMem j < <(TERM=dumb top -n 1 | grep Mem)`, where `j` is for `j`unk. Not that I'm saying this is a *good* way to do this ... just half as bad. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the pipe is the problem try something like this:

```
PorcUsado=$(echo "scale=2;$UsadoMem/$TotalMem" | bc -l)
```

i haven't tested it yet but you have to echo the string and pipe the result from `echo` to `bc`.

**EDIT**: Correcting the variable names

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: It did? Surprising, considering that the variable names aren't preceded by `$`.

Comment: Ops... its true... Works like a charm, when variables are preceded by $

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning `PorcUsado` to `scale=2;UsadoMem/TotalMem` and then piping the output of that assignment (nothing) into `bc`. You probably want the pipe inside a command substitution, e.g. (using a [here string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) instead of a pipe):

```
PorcUsado=$(bc -l <<<'scale=2;UsadoMem/TotalMem')
```

But you'll also need to evaluate those shell variables - `bc` can't do it for you:

```
PorcUsado=$(bc -l <<<"scale=2;$UsadoMem/$TotalMem")
```

Notice the use of `"` instead of `'` and the `$` prefix to allow Bash to evaluate the variables.

Also, if this is the whole script, you can just skip the `PorcUsado` variable at all and let `bc` write directly to stdout.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
TotalMem=$(top -n 1 | grep Mem | awk 'NR==1{print $4}') #integer
UsadoMem=$(top -n 1 | grep Mem | awk 'NR==1{print $8}') #integer
bc -l <<<"scale=2;$UsadoMem/$TotalMem"
```

Comment: I didn't know this way (with "<<<"). Thanks

Comment: @PedroAntônio they're called "here strings" (link in answer) and are a really nice tool for cases like this.

Answer (score 3):

Why pipe `top` output at all?  Seems too costly.

```
$ read used buffers < <(
    awk -F':? +' '
      {a[$1]=$2}
      END {printf "%d %d", a["MemTotal"]-a["MemFree"], a["Buffers"]}
    ' /proc/meminfo
  )
```

Of course, it can easily be a one-liner if you value brevity over readability.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `grep` or `bc`, since `awk` can search and do math all by itself:

```
top -n 1 -l 1 | awk '/Mem/ {printf "%0.2f\n",$8/$4;exit}'
```